# How to keep adding items to a div until both divs have same height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have two divs which are side by side. Currently, I display `n+2` items in left div and `n` items in right one. `n` varies based on category and is predetermined. My problem is sometimes individual items in left div have more height than usual. How can I keep adding items to the right div until both divs have about same height?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
var $left_div = $('#left_div');
var $right_div = $('#right_div');
while($left_div.height() > $right_div.height()){
   $right_div.append($your_item);
}
```

Where `$your_item` is defined as whatever you want to add onto your right div

Alternatively you can check for a threshold

```
var threshold = 200;
var $left_div = $('#left_div');
var $right_div = $('#right_div');

while(Math.abs($left_div.height() - $right_div.height()) < threshold){
   $right_div.append($your_item);
}
```